# How should I reuse a struct in a common lib, and change the json fields associated

Tags: json, go

I have a shared lib that has the following struct

```
//Measure struct
type Measure struct {
    Timestamp    time.Time `json:"timestamp"`
    Delta        float64   `json:"delta"`
    Redistribute float64   `json:"redistribute"`
}
```

Now, In my project, fields are ok, but json information may vary, I mean I could receive the info in my json with `json:"value"` instead of `json:"delta"`

How should I overload those values?

Comment: You'd need to define a new type with the appropriate JSON mappings.

Comment: Can I extend the original struct ?

Comment: No. You cannot change it outside of the package where it is defined.

Comment: If you create an equivalent type (same field types in the same order) with different struct tags, you can do a simple type conversion between the two.

Comment: Yes, but what I want to avoid is having duplicated types all over. Right now, my code has sever issues because everywhere I use differents object.

Comment: Well, I meant severe, but it is more about a big mess that real issue. But if each one of my services need to work on a custom object, I need to be very careful about divergence on all those common objects.

Comment: If you can distill the general problem into an easily understood question, we can probably help you solve the _actual problem_ you're facing more effectively, than with trying to force Go to do things it doesn't do.

Comment: Ok! Can you tell me why is it a bad question ?

Comment: I don't know why 4 people voted down, I can only guess as to their reasons. Some possibilities: 1. The question shows little or no research effort, 2. It doesn't show your current attempt, 3. it appears to be an XY Problem. Maybe someone had another reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How should I overload those values?

You shouldn't. There is no overloading in Go. You have two options:

1. Embed the type, and shadow the tags.

```golang
type OtherMeasure struct {
    pkg.Measure
    Delta        float64   `json:"value"`
}
```

2. Duplicate the struct.

```golang
type OtherMeasure struct {
    Timestamp    time.Time `json:"timestamp"`
    Delta        float64   `json:"value"`
    Redistribute float64   `json:"redistribute"`
}
```

Duplication is probably preferred for a small struct like this, because it is then possible to do a simple type conversion:

```
var om OtherMeasure = /* set the specific value */
var m Measure = Measure(om)
```